# How to write a SELECT for a field of type "quantity" in SET_GET_ENTITY method?

Tags: odata, abap, sap-gateway

I want to select a single row with all columns from my table `zbookings`. `zbookings` table has a structure based on `zbooking` data structure - see tables below.

Table `ZBOOKINGS`:
[image]

Structure `ZBOOKING`:
[image]

My `BOOKINGSET_GET_ENTITY` method:

```
method BOOKINGSET_GET_ENTITY.

    DATA: ls_keytab TYPE LINE OF /IWBEP/T_MGW_NAME_VALUE_PAIR,
          i_carrid TYPE string,
          i_connid TYPE string,
          i_fldate TYPE string,
          i_bookid TYPE string.

    LOOP AT it_key_tab INTO ls_keytab.
      CASE ls_keytab-name.
        WHEN 'Carrid'.
          i_carrid = ls_keytab-value.
        WHEN 'Connid'.
          i_connid = ls_keytab-value.
        WHEN 'Fldate'.
          i_fldate = ls_keytab-value.
        WHEN 'Bookid'.
          i_bookid = ls_keytab-value.
      ENDCASE.
    ENDLOOP.

    SELECT SINGLE *
      INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF er_entity
      FROM ybookings AS a
      WHERE
        a~carrid = i_carrid AND
        a~connid = i_connid AND
        a~fldate = i_fldate AND
        a~bookid = i_bookid.

endmethod.
```

I tested it via SAP Gateway Client. It's OK when I remove column `luggweight` from my `SELECT SINGLE *` statement. However when I select all columns via `SELECT SINGLE *`, then it outputs an error

> Runtime Error: 'SAPSQL_PARSER_TODO_WARNING'`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error>
  <code>SAPSQL_PARSER_TODO_WARNING</code>
  <message>Runtime Error: 'SAPSQL_PARSER_TODO_WARNING'. 
     The OData request processing has been abnormal terminated. If "Runtime Error"
     is not initial, launch transaction ST22 for details and analysis. Otherwise,
     launch transaction SM21 for system log analysis.</message>
  <timestamp>20190905144432</timestamp>
</error>
```

As you can see the problem is with `luggweight` field which is of `quantity` type and its typing method is `Type ref to`. When I check my `BOOKINGSET_GET_ENTITY` method via ctr+F2 it outputs a warning:

> The database field or the result type of the aggregate function LUGGWEIGHT and the component "LUGGWEIGHT" of "ER_ENTITY" are not compatible.

How should I modify my `SELECT` query / `BOOKINGSET_GET_ENTITY` method for it to work?

Comment: shouldn't your structure also have the component type S_LUGWEIGH? So it is linked to the correct data element?

Comment: why did you change standard structure? when I execute your code on standard booking table [it works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZyiv.png). Try to change `ybooking` to standard `booking`, I see your structure is missing component type for `LUGGWEIGH`,  having only elementary type, maybe that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

`Luggweight` field's typing method should be set to `Types` (not `Type ref to`) when creating / modifying `zbooking` data structure.